# How to launch com.android.launcher explicitly?

Tags: android-launcher

I have an app that replaces the launcher for a kiosk application. I need to exit to the stock launcher for service mode.

From a dummy test app I can start my own "home" app like this:

```
Context ctx = getBaseContext();
Intent i = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.application.main");
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

However, if I replace my.application.main with com.android.launcher, I get back null for the intent. Yet, com.android.launcher is on the system (Nexus 7 tablet). How do I launch com.android.launcher explicitly?